# Ok, i know i messed things up pretty bad..... virtualmin sub domain user taken over root login

Tags: permissions, users

ok, here is the scenario, i was playing around the import wizard and imported a subdomain i had created on a linode and now im having trouble cause the user i assigned to the subdomain is root. Now when i log into webmin / usermin / virtualmin with my root credentials, i end up administering a sub domain instead of working on the webmin root console.

Is there a way of 
a) deleting the virtualhost completely from usermin using ssh? 
b) rectifying this ..

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Probably virtualmin lost the relation between your virtualhost & system user. even if you have deleted the virtualhost. that username will be in system users list. So you will solve that without virtualmin.

you can remove user via Webmin. 
Logon to webmin > System > user & groups. find the user name on right. remove it. if it fails.

login to server via SSH > `su root`. then

`userdel [YOUR_VHOST_USERNAME]`

`groupdel [YOUR_VHOST_USERNAME]`